# Kendo nested arrays binding troubles

Tags: binding, kendo-ui, nested

I'm having troubles getting the kendo.binding working for a nested array. First level list rendering correct but second has some troubles.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oaken/kmy5adwv/5/)

Html:

```
<script  id="ul-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">        
    <h3>#=NAME#</h3>
    <ul data-template="il-template" data-bind="source: ad">

    </ul>
</script>

<script id="il-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li> #=ATT_NAME#</li>      
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
    var model = {items: [
        { NAME: "Group 1", ID: 1, ad: [{ ATT_NAME: "Attribute 1" }, { ATT_NAME: "Attribute 2" }] },
        { NAME: "Group 2", ID: 2, ad: [{ ATT_NAME: "Attribute 3" }, { ATT_NAME: "Attribute 4" }] },
        { NAME: "Group 3", ID: 3, ad: [{ ATT_NAME: "Attribute 5" }, { ATT_NAME: "Attribute 6" }] },
        { NAME: "Group 4", ID: 3, ad: [{ ATT_NAME: "Attribute 7" }, { ATT_NAME: "Attribute 8" }] }]};
    kendo.bind($('#view'), model);
```

Result:

```
<div id="view">
<div data-template="ul-template" data-bind="source: items">        
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
    <ul data-template="il-template" data-bind="source: ad">
    <li> Attribute 3</li>      

    <li> Attribute 4</li>      
</ul>

    <h3>Group 2</h3>
    <ul data-template="il-template" data-bind="source: ad">
    <li> Attribute 7</li>      

    <li> Attribute 8</li>      
</ul>

    <h3>Group 3</h3>
    <ul data-template="il-template" data-bind="source: ad">

    </ul>

    <h3>Group 4</h3>
    <ul data-template="il-template" data-bind="source: ad">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oaken/kmy5adwv/5/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to make sure that your question gets the best answer that it can as quickly as possible, please include a description of your problem and the code that causes the problem _in your question._  There is no guarantee that an outside site will keep content for long enough for the question to be helpful to future visitors. For good tips on this, take a look at the SO guide to asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask